# Passing a value to a plugin in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I've written a TinyMCE plugin and I need to pass a variable to it from my app.

I've tried setting `tinymce.activeEditor.my_var = 3;` after `tinymce.init();`. In the plugin, `editor.my_var` is always undefined.

How can I encode my own variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution.

When initialising the editor, you can pass it a custom variable, like so.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#editor_html',
    valid_elements: '*[*]',
    plugins: [
        "my_custom_plugin"
    ],
    my_custom_variable: 'test',
});
```

then in the plugin you should be able to access the variable with the following code:

```
editor.getParam("my_custom_variable");
```

Alternatively, you can use an ajax request to set a session variable, and then have the plugin also perform an ajax request to retrieve the session variable.